# Get all tables having Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to find a value wherever present in database.
Consider I need to find value "Fish" from Database.
Output I need is

```
 Table Name | Column Name  
--------------------------
 Table 1    |  columnName  
 Table 12   |  columnName
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Declare @SearchStr nvarchar(100) = 'YorValue' -- Here type your text
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET @ColumnName = ''
   SET @TableName = 
(
    SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                OBJECT_ID(
                    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                     ), 'IsMSShipped'
                       ) = 0
)

WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName =
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
            AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
            AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
    )

    IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Results
        EXEC
        (
            'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
            FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
            ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
        )
    END
 END 
 END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
drop table #Results
```

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE 'your column name'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Dilip, Your query works perfectly fine for Column Name But I need to find from The Value.